# cannot read parent field from cascaded child object

Tags: visualforce

I have the current relationship: parent - child object1 - child object2.
I am not able to read a field using VisualForce on a parent object from child object2.

I am able to create a formula field using Force.com with the following formula:

```
Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__r.Audit__r.Model_Year__c
```

I am not able to read the same field within my visualforce page using:

```
<apex:variable var="VehicleInformation" value="{!Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__r.Audit__r.Model_Year__c}" />
```

---

Using this controller, how would I get the Id of the grandparent? Currently it is getting the Id of the immediate page.

Getting Error: `Error: Unknown property 'Auto_Vehicle__cStandardController.vehicle'`

```
public with sharing class ParentChildExtensionVEHICLEsample {
    public Audit__c audit;
    public Auto_Vehicle__c vehicle;

    String accId;

    public ParentChildExtensionVEHICLEsample(ApexPages.StandardController standardController){
        //accID=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
        accID='a0YJ00000036njqMAA';   // try to hardcode a know parent Id. 

        //insert if condition to test for new instantiation or existing object is being opened. 
        //audit= [SELECT Id, Policy_Number__c FROM Audit__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId') LIMIT 1];
        vehicle= [SELECT Id, Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__r.Audit__r.Model_Year__c FROM Auto_Vehicle__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId') LIMIT 1];
    }

    public Audit__c getAudit(){
        return audit;
    }

    public Auto_Vehicle__c getAuto_Vehicle(){
        return vehicle;
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page standardController="Auto_Vehicle__c" readOnly="false" extensions="ParentChildExtensionVEHICLEsample" >
    <!--Contoller Information variables --> 
    <!-- <apex:variable var="a" value="{!audit}" />  --> 
    <apex:variable var="a" value="{!vehicle}" />
    <apex:form id="form1">
        <apex:pageBlock id="block1" title="Personal Auto Audit Sample Data" >
            Hello {!$User.FirstName}!  <font color='blue'> Enter audit information for this sample below. </font>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="testsection1" title="TEST & Debug Section" >
                ....Parent ID Number is : "{!a.Policy_Number__c}"<br></br> 
                <script>
                    twistSection(document.getElementById("{!$Component.testsection1}").childNodes[0].childNodes[0]);
                </script>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way you would be able to read that field in a Visualforce page is if you queried for the field on the property in your controller:

```
SELECT Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__r.Audit__r.Model_Year__c FROM CHILD_2 WHERE...
```

Related parent/grandparents do not exist on the sObject in memory in your apex controller without being queried.

Comment: Since the requesting object is the grandchild how would I structure the ID lookup ?   For example the grandchild object controller would collect several fields as:  vehicle= [Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__r.Audit__r.Model_Year__c FROM Audit__c WHERE Id = parentId];   But this only goes up to the child object. How do I traverse up to the parent Id ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the field being requested in the query we both posted is on the grandparent, not the immediate parent.

Comment: Appreciate you help. Let me clarify. Parent=Audit, Child=Auto_Audit_Sample-Policy, grandchild=Auto_Vehicle. My visualforce page for Auto_Vehicle needs to pull in fields from Audit. Not sure how to grab the ID of Audit from Auto_Vehicle.

Comment: if I use Id=parentId I'm only looking up one level to Auto_Audit_Sample-Policy which does not have the field.

Comment: The Id of audit as it relates to Auto Vehicle is something like Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__r.Audit__c

Comment: I added a controller to my initial question. What I'm not sure of is how to get the Id of Parent (Audit ) from this controller for the Auto_Vehicle. See : accID=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');

Comment: You don't need the Id of the Audit, nor do you need to query the Audit object, you should just query the Auto Vehicle object and you can pull any fields looking up to parent/grandparent/etc. from a query on that grandchild.

Comment: can you post an example ? I do need to pull in several other fields from the grandparent object in order to render / or not render apex components on the Vehicle (grandchild) visualforce page.

Comment: I did post an example where the query is on the grandchild object up to the grandparent.

Comment: Thanks, was looking at the side by side edits and didn't realize you were referring to your original snippet. i just edited the controller and added the VF page. getting an error: Unknown property 'Auto_Vehicle__cStandardController.vehicle    Auto_Vehicle__c is the grandchild object.

Answer (score 0):

What's the field on audit__c, is it auto_audit_sample_policy__c? If so, you wouldn't need the plural when looking up to that field (i.e. [Select auto_audit_sample_policy__r.auto_audit_vehicles__r.Model_year__c from audit__c ...]